# SVN Log XML Output: Get Revision Number as a Node

Tags: xml, svn

When I run `svn log --xml 'repos'` . It generates the log like...

```
<logentry revision="1">
<author>harry</author>
<date>2008-06-03T06:35:53.048870Z</date>
<msg>Initial Import.</msg>
</logentry>
```

Can it be outputed as

```
<logentry>
<revision>1</revision>
<author>harry</author>
<date>2008-06-03T06:35:53.048870Z</date>
<msg>Initial Import.</msg>
</logentry>
```

This will help me parse it easily to insert the data into the database. Or is there any easy way to store the log to a database.

Comment: Why is reading an attribute a problem? I don't think I've ever seen a XML library where reading attribute would be more difficult than reading node value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without compiling your own custom Subversion client with the modifications you're after, you can't.

Alternatively, you could pass the XML through an XSLT stylesheet to perform the transform(s) you're after, and then feed *that* into your database.

Or simply parse the XML yourself (every programming/scripting language has an XML library built in, or easily obtained) to perform the inserts.

Answer (score 1):

PanBI has a svn module which gives an OLAP interface to svn log: http://sourceforge.net/projects/panbi/

It generates a svn.sql with all your log. You can use the sql to dump in to any db you want